# Am I able to move a question of mine from SuperUser to IT Security?

Tags: support, moving-questions, privileges

Namely, [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/256617/how-to-customize-seahorse-plugin-behavior-in-nautilus)? And, if not, what is the Right Way to ask for it to be moved?

Answer (score 3):

Since IT Security is in beta, it's unlikely to be moved there unless a convincing argument has been made for its migration.

You can put a case for such when you flag for moderator attention.

This is the same for other questions for other Stack Exchanges which fall out of the most logical selections in the five set migration choices allowed (four if you discount meta).